# PowershellCore - get content of non 20x response without exception

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowershellCore 6.2.3, I want to get full content of a non 20x response (it's 30x actually), but Powershell gave me an exception instead.

The request I sent:

```bsh
iwr -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868'
```

Exception:

```
iwr : Response status code does not indicate success: 302 (Moved Temporarily).
At line:1 char:1
+ iwr -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri ([System.Uri]('https:// ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Method: HEAD, Reque\u2026PowerShell/6.2.3
}:HttpRequestMessage) [Invoke-WebRequest], HttpResponseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Then I went ahead and created a function:

```bsh
function Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch() {
    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest $args
    } catch {
        $_.Exception.Response
    }
}
```

However, when I called it like this:

```bsh
Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868"
```

It outputs nothing.

Then I changed the function a little bit:

```bsh
function Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch() {
    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest $args
    } catch {
        $_.Exception
    }
}
```

This time it gave me an error:

```
Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Uri' required by parameter 'Uri'. Specified method is not supported.
```

I tried other 2 calls but made no difference:

```bsh
Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868'
Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri ([System.Uri]('https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868'))
```

My questions are:

1. Where does that `System.Object[]` come from? It treats the URL string as an object array?
2. Why doesn't the casting ( `([System.Uri]('https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868'))` ) work?
3. What else am I doing wrong here so that I can't get content of that 302 response?

Comment: Try with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`: `(iwr -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).RawContent`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Invoke-WebRequest` isn't actually being called in either of your `Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch` implementations - PowerShell is throwing a `ParameterBindingException` instead, but it's only being surfaced in the second example.

If we add a bit of logging to your first versions you get this:

```bsh
PS> function Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch() {
    try {
        write-host "invoke"
        Invoke-WebRequest $args
    } catch {
        write-host "catch"
        write-host $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
        write-host $_.Exception.Message
        write-host ($null -eq $_.Exception.Response)
        $_.Exception.Response
    }
}

PS> Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868"
invoke
catch
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException
Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Uri' required by parameter 'Uri'. Specified method is not supported.
True
```

I think the first issue is that your call to Invoke-WebRequest is equivalent to `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $args`, and you need to be [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) your $args into Invoke-WebRequest instead (note the example below uses `@args`, not `$args` to execute the "splatting"):

```bsh
PS> function Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch() {
    try {
        write-host "invoke"
        Invoke-WebRequest @args
    } catch {
        write-host "catch"
        write-host $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
        write-host $_.Exception.Message
        $_.Exception.Response
    }
}

PS> Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868"
invoke


StatusCode        : 302
StatusDescription : Moved Temporarily
Content           : {}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
                    Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:b47e5e27-bf85-45ba-a97c-0377ce0e5779
                    X-Response-Cache-Status: True
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Strict-Transport-Security: ...
Headers           : {[Request-Context, appId=cid-v1:b47e5e27-bf85-45ba-a97c-0377ce0e5779], [X-Response-Cache-Status, True], [Pragma, no-cache], [Connection, keep-alive]...}
RawContentLength  : 0

Invoke-WebRequest : The maximum redirection count has been exceeded. To increase the number of redirections allowed, supply a higher value to the -MaximumRedirection parameter.
At line:4 char:9
+         Invoke-WebRequest @args
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MaximumRedirectExceeded,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

The second part of your problem is that once `Invoke-WebRequest` is being called correctly, it *is* returning the 302 response, so you just need to suppress the exception with `-ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"`:

```bsh
PS> function Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch() {
    Invoke-WebRequest @args -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
}

PS> Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch -Method 'HEAD' -MaximumRedirection 0 -Uri "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868"


StatusCode        : 302
StatusDescription : Moved Temporarily
Content           : {}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
                    Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:b47e5e27-bf85-45ba-a97c-0377ce0e5779
                    X-Response-Cache-Status: True
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Strict-Transport-Security: ...
Headers           : {[Request-Context, appId=cid-v1:b47e5e27-bf85-45ba-a97c-0377ce0e5779], [X-Response-Cache-Status, True], [Pragma, no-cache], [Connection, keep-alive]...}
RawContentLength  : 0
```

To summarise:

1. Where does that System.Object[] come from? It treats the URL string as an object array?

It's the `$args` variable which is being passed in as the positional `-Uri` parameter, rather than splatted.

2. Why doesn't the casting ( (System.Uri) ) work?

Because bundling a string *or* a uri value into the `$args` variable still results in a ParameterBindingException when you pass `$args` as the positional `-Uri` parameter.

3. What else am I doing wrong here so that I can't get content of that 302 response?

Just suppress the exception with `-ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"`.

**Update for PowerShell Core**

From testing, `Invoke-WebRequest` works slightly differently for PowerShell Core but you can use this instead:

```
function Invoke-WebRequest-With-Try-Catch() {
    try
    {
        Invoke-WebRequest @args
    }
    catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException]
    {
        return $_.Exception.Response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation! However `-ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"` still makes no difference on my end. Are you using PowershellCore 6 or WindowsPowershell 5.1?

Comment: I was using PowerShell 5.1. I'll take another look tonight with Core tonight...

Comment: Never mind, I tried it in WindowsPowershell 5.1 and it worked. It's reasonable for these 2 versions to behave differently.